# Loading My.Settings.PropertyValues into a grid

Tags: vb.net

I am looking to create a settings form where the user can see all of the `My.Settings`

My code goes as follows:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
Dim settignName As String
Dim settingValue As String

For Each setting In My.Settings.PropertyValues
    settignName = setting.Name.ToString
    settingValue = setting.

    dtSettings.Rows.Add(settignName, settingValue)
    Console.WriteLine(settignName, settingValue)

   Next

End Sub
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45393126/9365244) - I think it will direct you appropriately

Comment: With `Option Strict On`, you'd have an immediate summary of what's wrong with that code and immediate suggestions that allow to fix it. For example, change your loop in `For Each setting As SettingsPropertyValue In My.Settings.PropertyValues [...] Next`. No late binding, no use of Object, all Properties available in Intellisense, no mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim settignName As String
    Dim settingValue As String

    For Each setting As System.Configuration.SettingsPropertyValue In My.Settings.PropertyValues
        settignName = setting.Name.ToString
        settingValue = setting.PropertyValue.ToString

        dtSettings.Rows.Add(settignName, settingValue)
        Console.WriteLine(settignName, settingValue)
    Next
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. `My.Settings.Properties` is a collection of `SettingProperty`. You can then access the properties of `SettingProperty` like `Name`, `PropertyType` and `DefaultValue`.

This code requires `Imports System.Configuration`

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    For Each s As SettingsProperty In My.Settings.Properties
        Debug.Print($"{s.Name} - {s.PropertyType} - {s.DefaultValue}")
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: [How to get the current value of a Property Setting at run-time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60117461/7444103)